# Run prerequisite based on 32 or 64 bit OS

Tags: inno-setup

How would I check if the system is 32 or 64 bit and then run the correct silverlight installer?

```
[Run]
Filename: "{tmp}\Silverlight_x64.exe"; Check: SilverlightIsNotInstalled ; Flags: nowait

[code]
function SilverlightIsNotInstalled: Boolean;
   begin
Result := not RegKeyExists(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Silverlight');
end;
```

Comment: [`This way`](http://pastebin.com/XA7hF40E). Sorry, I don't have time to post answer with a few words...

Comment: This gives me an error saying that there cannot be multiple check commands...

Comment: Ah, sorry. You already have a check there. Checks are usually written at the end of the entry, so I've overlooked it.

Comment: `Check: SilverlightIsNotInstalled and IsWin64`